# build a histogram in python with one column as x axis and 3 columns as y axes

Tags: python, histogram

I have the following data

```
method,RequirementT,RequirementN,RequirementU
1,1,7,0
2,0,0,8
3,2,6,0
4,1,7,0
5,2,6,0
6,2,6,0
```

Here is a link to my full data 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aBRy2uf34kjWQAo8nUDMnuAEHPR4XBMD/view?usp=sharing

I would like to built a histogram in python such that the x axis corresponds to the first column of my data (method) and the three other columns (RequirementT, RequirementN, RequirementU) are represented in the y axis. I would like the graph to be under the form of a histogram.

I have tried `df.plot.bar(x='method', y=['RequirementT', 'RequirementN', 'RequirementU'])`
 and this gives me the following output which is obviously wrong, completely non readable and I don't know why there is these thick black lines around the x axis 
[image]

Comment: cool! what have you tried?

Comment: just added  whaht I tried

Comment: The output is not _obviously wrong_ in my opinion. This is what happens when you make a histogram with many variables in X. What kind of plot are you trying to make exactly?

Comment: whats wrong with that? For me the figure is exactly what you explained..

Comment: how can I have a normal x axis not looking crazy like the current one? I am willing to use an interval with 50 ticks if that makes it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
df.plot.bar(x='method', y=['RequirementT', 'RequirementN', 'RequirementU'])
```

[image]

Are you looking for a distribution plot? Try this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = df.set_index('method', drop=True)

sns.distplot(df.iloc[:, 0], bins=10) # just use .loc and insert your 3 columns instead of 0, 1, 2
sns.distplot(df.iloc[:, 1], bins=10)
sns.distplot(df.iloc[:, 2], bins=10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: tried it but I have a new issue I just edited my post showing the problem I have

Comment: I think you might be looking for a distribution plot? See edit.

Comment: no I want a barplot with intervals as my x axis so for example, I would like three bars (requirementT, requirementN, requirementU) shown for the interval [1,50], the same three bars shown for the interval [50,100] and so on until the interval [750, 800]